# how to get user IP address in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Iam using Mvc4,
 I want to get the users ip address of who are using my site.
[Based on this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/582491/ImplementingplusAuditplusTrailsplususingplusASP-NE)
I can get user host address, But i want to get exact user ip address

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the place you are.

Controller:

```
ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Razor View:

```
@Request.UserHostAddress
```

Model:

Do not use System.Web.HttpContext since it's very hard, if not impossible to unit test. Instead, pass the value in through your controller.

Html Helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Ip(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    string html = html.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress;
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(html);
}
```

Keep in mind, due to simplicity of the examples, I didn't do any null-checking.

Comment: Iam hosting my site in server, By using this code am getting only that server Ip address. But I want users ip address

Comment: This is no longer true in ASP.NET 5 [Core 1.0 (vnext)] :(

Comment: @ppumkin Thanks for the heads up. Also, I must comment my own answer that System.Web.HttpContext is actually easy to test with Microsoft Fakes which ships with VS Premium and up. But I won't be changing my answer since I still think it's relevant to stay away from. Especially with vNext which is severing its ties with System.Web.

Answer (score 3):

Try using following code

```
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Comment: Hi @Neel I've used above mentioned code but I'm getting empty text... Have you encountered this before? Any help?

Comment: I will have to check